# Arquivo ReportView não consigo visualizar o Design

Tags: c#

Estou começando a utilizar o Report View, mas estou com um problema. Quando crio um projeto com o template Report o arquivo gerado não consigo abrir o design, somente consigo visualizar este código, conforme abaixo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Width>6.5in</Width>
  <Body>
    <Height>2in</Height>
  </Body>
  <rd:ReportTemplate>true</rd:ReportTemplate>
  <Page>
  </Page>
</Report>
```

Tem como solucionar isto ?.

Answer (score 0):

Este é o código.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  Width>6.5in
  Body>
    2in
  /Body>
  rd:ReportTemplate>true
  Page>
  /Page>
/Report